# Can the 'stages' construction in a declarative Jenkinsfile be create from a function?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a bunch of stages that run for different `agent` in parallel. For example:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Build and Test") {
            parallel {
                stage("Windows") {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label "Windows"
                        }
                    }
                    stages {
                        stage("Stage 1") {
                            steps {
                                sh "echo Stage 1"
                            }
                        }
                        stage("Stage 2") {
                            steps {
                                sh "echo Stage 2"
                            }
                        }
                        stage("Stage 3") {
                            steps {
                                sh "echo Stage 3"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage("macOS") {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label "macOS"
                        }
                    }
                    stages {
                        stage("Stage 1") {
                            steps {
                                sh "echo Stage 1"
                            }
                        }
                        stage("Stage 2") {
                            steps {
                                sh "echo Stage 2"
                            }
                        }
                        stage("Stage 3") {
                            steps {
                                sh "echo Stage 3"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the stages are the repeated for the two platforms.

Is it possible to isolate the definition of those stages in a function so that they can be reused (and DRY)?

Comment: There are multiple ways; You can move to a Pipeline "Shared Library" to add helper style classes; this plus a (optional) Inversion of Control style pattern to hold the pipeline context (`this`) (or directly sending it to the helper style classes) allows you to lower repetition.  Alternatively it might be possible to move those steps to a downstream job/build/pipeline